How to find out why git clone/fetch are slow?
I work at a company with a large monorepo and right now it takes ~45s to checkout the repo in CI, which is slower than I'd like.
I've already done what I can to optimize the git commands, both of the following techniques give about the same result and are faster than everything else I've tried:
git init
git remote add origin $REPO 
git fetch --depth 1 origin $COMMIT_HASH
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

or
git clone --depth=1 --single-branch $REPO

I assume there's something about my repo that is slow, because using the same techniques I can checkout facebook/react in < 3 seconds.
Is there some way I can profile git and get a report on why these operations are slow and what I could do about it?

How does the size of your repo compare to that of the react repo (bytes, file count, folder count)?

Set environment variable GIT_TRACE. See examples at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22GIT_TRACE%22
